# Node.js HTTP request returns 2 chunks (data bodies)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I'm trying to get the source of an HTML file with an HTTP request in node.js - my problem is that it returns data twice. Here is my code:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        if(chunk.length > 1000) {
            console.log(chunk.length);
        }
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("error" + e.message);
    });
});

req.end();
```

This then returns:

```
5637
3703
```

The hell! When I just console.log(chunk), it returns all the data as if it were one large string, and when I add a something like console.log("data starts here") in the res.on('data', it returns the whole string with the "data starts here" somewhere in the middle, implying it's just being split.

Every test I do returns 2 values and it's really annoying. I can just do "if(chunk.length > 4000)" but given the nature of the page I'm getting, this could change. How can I make it so that all the data returns in one large chunk?

Comment: The last one might be a request for `favicon.ico`

Comment: This is perfectly normal behavior... `console.log(chunk)`'ll give you the request results as they arrive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not "2 data bodies", these are 2 chunks(pieces) of the same body, you have to concatenate them.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    var body = '';

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    // Streams2 API
    res.on('readable', function () {
        var chunk = this.read() || '';

        body += chunk;
        console.log('chunk: ' + Buffer.byteLength(chunk) + ' bytes');
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('body: ' + Buffer.byteLength(body) + ' bytes');
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("error" + e.message);
    });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: When you set an `encoding`, you do not get `buffer objects` http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers. (You can get the `.length` like this http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data). ; )

Comment: @dollarVar, with `String.length` you don't get the actual byte length because unicode characters can occupy more bytes, for example `'acasă'.length` is 5 but `Buffer.byteLength('acasă')'acasă'` is 6, think about :)

Comment: Hey, I see what you mean (+1). Do you get an idea of how to set it up on http://runnable.com to prove it?

Comment: I mean, that you get a `buffer object` at all, that was how I understood the specs, you do not get one (when you set the encoding).

Comment: @dollarVar, http://runnable.com/Uwyzv6VsK55PAACO/buffer-bytelength-for-node-js , `res` is a readable stream which will produce buffers by default, to make it produce strings the encoding must set to `utf8`, but to get the real length in bytes the `Buffer.byteLength` is being used.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I meant the production environment had to capture a stream (online) and then see if the `buffer object` is created `.on('data')` as in `readable.on('data')`? (When the encoding is set).

Comment: Ok, short answer "It works both". (Keep another +1 in mind). Long answer: tried with that code locally http://runnable.com/UwzJAZ_tkXxQAABs/bufferifencodingset-for-node-js but still do not know hwo to `curl` into it on runnable; the command is known, but only in the terminal before `Run`, not in the obvious `console` after clicking `Run`. :/1