# How do I use Plupload with Node.js and show the percentages of upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, plupload

Currently, my code works. However, when a file is uploaded, no percentages are sent back to the javascript code.  (I guess my server needs to send the chunk percentage back?)

The "UploadProgress" event just prints "0" when it's complete.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#button_holder").show();
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            browse_button : 'pickfiles',
            container : 'button_holder',
            multi_selection: true,
            url : '/upload',
            flash_swf_url : '/js/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url : '/js/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
        });

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
            $("#button_holder").hide(); 

            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                var item = '<div class="upload_item" id="' + file.id + '">' + '<b class="percent"></b></div>' + file.name + ', ' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + '</div>'
                $("#progress_holder").append(item);
            }); 

            uploader.start();
            return false;
        });

        uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(uploader, file, response){
            if(response.status == 200){ 
                var icon = "<i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>";
            }else{
                var icon = "<i class='fa fa-times fa-fw'></i>";
            }
            var html = '<div class="success_item">' + icon + ' ' + file.name + '</div>';
            $("#progress_holder").append(html);
        });

        uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(uploader, files){
        });

        uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
            console.log(file.percent); //just says "0"
            $("#" + file.id).first(".percent").html(file.percent + "%");
            return false;
        });
        uploader.init();
    });
</script>
```

This is my backend code:

```
var express = require('express');
var Pluploader = require('node-pluploader');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');


var app = express();
app.set('views','/home/user/heaven/templates');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('/home/user/heaven/media'));



var pluploader = new Pluploader({
  uploadLimit: 100, //MB
  uploadDir: '/home/user/heaven/uploads'
});

pluploader.on('fileUploaded', function(file, req) {
  console.log(file);
});
pluploader.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    pluploader.handleRequest(req, res);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {});
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening to server.');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a chunk_size in the Uploader options ?

Comment: tried ur code just now , with ui from `http://www.plupload.com/examples/core` 
it works fine, uploaded a 300mb file, it shows percentage incrementing, no issue , only difference was 
`var pluploader = new Pluploader({
  uploadLimit: 500, //MB
  //uploadDir: '/uploads'
});`

Comment: i meant i commented out upload directory ,also added cors headers like 
`//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
}`

`html : http://pastie.org/10499488`

vl try ur code too later

Comment: also in ur code i changed url to `url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload',`

Comment: @TIMEX what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I am getting separate requests for each and every chunk. Is that the way it works? if then, How to combine all the chunks to make a file out of it? @Aishwat Singh

Comment: @VishnuIT sorry I haven't touched Node in long time, but any uploader will send back file in chunks and that gets combined as blob in your browser I guess, take a look at this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015673/node-js-http-request-returns-2-chunks-data-bodies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change url to:

```
url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload'
```

and instead of binding `UploadProgress` later, do it in init, like this:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            browse_button: 'pickfiles',
            container: 'button_holder',
            multi_selection: true,
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload',
            flash_swf_url: '/js/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: '/js/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
            init: {
                UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                    console.log('file%: '+file.percent);

                }
            }
        });
```

I tested, it works in your code. The same thing doesn't work with bind, which is quite weird. I'll figure it out later.

Server code: https://github.com/aishwat/plupload_server

Client code: https://github.com/aishwat/plupload_client/blob/master/examples/custom.html

And if you don't want to use Plupload, there's another way using XMLHttpRequest progress event, something like:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {});
```

Here's the [node.js code using this approach](https://github.com/hiiamrohit/nodeJs-file-upload) (written by [Rohit Kumar](https://github.com/hiiamrohit)).

Comment: sorry for all the hustle , in ur code at uploadProgress bind just remove `return false` and it vl work . 
 `uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
            console.log(file.percent); 
            return false; <-- remove this 
        });`

I guess this one is pretty self explanatory to why it was giving 0 all the time